# Cómo subir un archivo de excel en HTML5 colocar los datos recibidos en input text?

Tags: angularjs, html5, excel

Tengo un botón el cual al presionarlo debe hacer un upload de un archivo de excel xls o xlsx que solo tiene dos columnas, pero aun no he lograrlo hacerlo con esta librería http://sheetjs.com/ quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar en como resolver ese problema.
y lo mejor es que debo hacer un upload del archivo y los datos que reciba mandarlos a varios input text pero con el mismo botón.
gracias por su gran ayuda!!!

Comment: No entiendo tienes que hacer un "upload" o un "download"? Que tipo de servidor tienes, que código has escrito?

Comment: El lenguaje es html y asi como lo acabas de hacer es perfecto solo faltaría que los datos recibidos los capture y los posicione en input text

Comment: Podrías darle una lectura a: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask por favor?

Comment: Agrega más detalles, caso contrario tu pregunta tiende potencialmente a ser cerrada porque "No está claro lo que se pregunta", te he respondido en base a lo que he entendido, espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx Si la pregunta esta marcada como angular entonces es muy probable que deba usar [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: @JBS Lo que quieres no se puede hacer con HTML. Dirás con JavaScript. Aun no queda claro lo que quieres porque no has intentado nada.

Comment: @devconcept efectivamente, no me percaté de la etiqueta angular, vi la de HTML5 y efectos de inercia :D

Comment: lo que quiero decir es como se puede subir un archivo de excel con angularjs y los datos que capture mandarlos a los input text de mi formulario en html5

Comment: @JBS Ese es el problema. La librería que referencias no hace un upload como tal sino que lo lee desde el mismo cliente. Es esto lo que quieres?

Comment: lo que quiero es el la pagina web lea el archivo de excel  locamente y los datos leidos los coloque en los input text y de alli solo tendria que tomar los datos para mandarlos a una grafica que ya tengo con canvas la cual es esta http://jsfiddle.net/8xw8J/564/

Comment: creo que ya te entendí bien: lo que quieres es que el excel contenga los datos y tu web se encargue de graficar las barras estadísticas, en ese caso te recomiendo guardar el archivo de excel como .csv y utilices la librería D3.js https://d3js.org/ y aquí un ejemplo: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/how-to-import-data-from-csv-file-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muchas gracias a todos, ya solucione el detalle de la carga de archivos con modificaciones de esta Liberia: http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/.
ahora le que voy a ver es como paso los datos recibidos por el documento .xls a el gráfico. seria de gran ayuda si podrían guiarme en este paso.

Comment: Me parece perfecto hermano! Felicitaciones! :D Te recomiendo que edites esta respuesta con la nueva información y que aceptes tu respuesta porque es la que ha resuelto tu duda. Sigue con todo el power 2.0!

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('archivoParaSubir').addEventListener('change', function(){
        var file = this.files[0];        
        console.log("name : " + file.name);
        console.log("size : " + file.size);
        console.log("type : " + file.type);
        console.log("date : " + file.lastModified);
    }, false);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="archivoParaSubir" />
<input type="submit" value="Subir archivo" name="submit">
</form>
```

Seleccionando un `PDF` por ejemplo, tengo esto como resultado en la **consola del navegador**:

```
name : Certificate_1.pdf  _display:47:9
size : 820172  _display:48:9
type : application/pdf  _display:49:9
date : 1461866804000
```

Ahora, te recomiendo que en el backend es donde debes procesar ese archivo, te da mayor flexibilidad. Por cierto, agrega más detalles para obtener mejores respuestas.